# High MySQL bandwidth in PHP application

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-ec2, bandwidth, amazon-rds

I am having a PHP application (Drupal) in an Amazon EC2 server and have the MySQL DB (Maria Db) in RDS. For some reason there is few 100 TB of bandwidth consumed in RDS. My site is behind Varnish and Cloudflare. Except of new or edited content all contents are cached in Varnish or CF. 99% of cache tables are in memcache and not MySQL.

How can I find out what is consuming so much bandwidth in my MySQL server? Is there a way to know from where and what is the connection about and what is eating up all the bandwidth?

Comment: may be dumps, backups

Comment: You can enable general logging on MySQL and that will log all SQL statements executed on the server. (generates lots of log data!)

Comment: But would it allow me to know from which source request are coming and what tables are read most?